# Dynamic field performance

Tags: performance, groovy, hibernate, grails

A have a model with a dynamic field like so:

```
def resolveClient() {
    if (prevCall && prevCall.client) {
        return prevCall.client
    } else {
        return client
    }
}
```

Pretty simple. However, using a dynamic field makes me unable to do queries at the database level. I can't query using HQL or Criteria. This seems to be impacting performance pretty heavily. What's a better method to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve the client with a GORM/Hibernate query you basically need to persist the resolved client value.

Based on your `resolveClient()` method I'm assuming your domain class model goes something like this:

```
class SomeDomainClass {
    Call prevCall
    Client client

    def resolveClient() {
        if (prevCall && prevCall.client) {
            return prevCall.client
        } else {
            return client
        }
    }
}

class Call {
    Client
}

class Client { }
```

If you were dealing with two properties that were in the `SomeDomainClass` then you'd probably be able to use a [derived property](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties). But since one of the properties in an association, a derived property won't work. Instead, you can do this:

```
class SomeDomainClass {
    Call prevCall
    Client client
    Client resolvedClient

    def resolveClient() {
        prevCall?.client ?: client
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        resolvedClient = resolveClient()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        resolvedClient = resolveClient()
    }
}
```

The new property `resolvedClient`, which is maintained by the `beforeInsert()` and `beforeUpdate()` methods, takes care of saving the current *resolved client* to the GORM store (database). With that value persisted you can use it in GORM queries:

```
def instances = SomeDomainClass.where {
    resolvedClient == someClient
}.list()
```

On the Groovy side, it would still be best to use the `resolveClient()` method because the `resolvedClient` property can get out of sync if `prevCall` changes.

```
def client = instance.resolveClient()
```

Comment: Thanks, Emmanuel. That's basically what I ended up doing. I already have an `update` method for my domain, so I just tacked the resolved client onto that.  (I also tried calling a stored function from a derived property, but this is an abstract domain class, and apparently GORM or Grails doesn't support derived properties on those :/ )